# Is it possible to miss WebSocket event during time.sleep\wait?

Tags: python, websocket, em-websocket-client

Is it possible to miss websocket event during time.sleep \ wait function, or program load, in a synchronous running program?

**Example:**

1. Server sent event #1 which triggered some heavy processing. For the
   sake of this example, let's assume it's a simple "wait\sleep"
   function for 10 seconds.
2. During that time server sends event #2.

Will client receive this event #2 after those 10 seconds? Can server see whether client is ready to receive next event or not?

I'm using python - and websocket-client to receive messages from a websocket server.